# Can not join comp to the domain... greyed out

Tags: windows-xp, domain

I have an old WinXP Pro SP3 computer I need to join to the domain, simple right? not really. When I go to control panel -> system -> computer name and click on CHANGE ("rename this computer") everything is greyed out. I can not set it from workgroup to a domain.

[image]

I am logged on locally as an admin. (Builtin account and one I created)
I have checked local policy (gpedit.msc) on the comp, but it feels like a needle in the haystack. I could probably reload an image faster than trying to fix this...but I am curious so I post here to see if anyone knows of it/fix.

I tried reseting the policy to defaults, but no luck:

```
secedit /configure /cfg %windir%\repair\secsetup.inf /db secsetup.sdb /verbose
```

**EDIT1:**
[image]

**EDIT2: Computer Browser & Workstation Services are not running**

- The Workstation service terminated with service-specific error 2250 (0x8CA).
- The Computer Browser service depends on the Workstation service which failed to start because of the following error:
- The service has returned a service-specific error code.
- Could not load RDR device driver.

**EDIT3: "mrxsmb.sys" in system32/drivers is a trojan, which is needed for WorkStation**

Comment: Are you positive that this is a pro machine and not home edition?

Comment: When you go to control panel -> system -> general it does state WinXP Pro Sp3. I checked this like 3-4 times to make sure :) Because that was my first thought.

Comment: Do you have the "Computer Browser" service present and started?

Comment: actually no it is not, WORKSTATION is not either

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer and mark it accepted when you are able.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Client for Microsoft Networks](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/clientformsnetworks.mspx?mfr=true) needs to be installed and enabled on the network adapter that is on the Windows network.

[image]

Then determine if your workstation service is started. The workstation service is required to join a domain:

[image]

Comment: It did have Client for Microsoft Networks. I posted a screen grab from the network connections dialog above.

Comment: Workstation service is not running.

Comment: @Logman Workstation service needs to be running.

Comment: Yes, I tried turning the service on but it failed. Checked the event logs briefy, but I did not get much chance to dig deep into it yet. I have to do this remotely, and it is in a busy office (front desk).

Comment: I was going to uninstall the network properties..."Client for MS Networks" and "File and Print Sharing" to start...but do it remotely with a person on hand that has no comp knowledge..eek

Comment: well found out that the "mrxsmb.sys" in system32/drivers is a trojan, which is needed for WorkStation